# Adding delegate protocol conformance to pure swift class

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am using a package that declares an open class A, which I can't modify.

In my code, I'd like to declare class B as inheriting from this A class, and also conform to a delegate protocol (`HMHomeManagerDelegate` in my case).

`class B: A, HMHomeManagerDelegate {`

The compiler is telling me : "Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'HomesList' should inherit 'NSObject' instead" - and that's because `HMHomeManagerDelegate` inherits from `NSObjectProtocol`, and I shall therefore provide all NSObjectProtocol's required methods in B.

But that means a lot of boiler plate code (some of which being non-trivial)...

Is there any better pattern ?

Comment: @Dima [`HMHomeManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhomemanagerdelegate) is a part of Apple HomeKit framework, you cannot remove NSObjectProtocol conformance from it.

Comment: Oh, oops I wasn't familiar with that one, then that's a no-go. Deleting my comment to avoid confusion, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of possible options is to make a separate class `MyHome`, which implements `HMHomeManagerDelegate`, and then use it inside of class `B`.

```
class MyHome: NSObject, HMHomeManagerDelegate { ... }

class B: A {
    let myHome = MyHome()

    // and all communication with HomeKit will go through MyHome class
    // ...
}
```

If your project is small, I guess `MyHome` will look like a useless wrapper. But in a bigger application I can imagine that `MyHome` is responsible for convenient communication with HomeKit, so `class B` makes decisions while `MyHome` serves it (prepares/modifies some data which goes to/from HomeKit).

Comment: Thanks, I was slowly coming to this too. I also investigated having B inside of MyHome. I guess, it's best to choose the way that needs the less wrapper code.